# SSIS Package Deployment Utility - configure deployment location

Tags: ssis

Is there a way to configure the generated SSIS deployment wizard (manifest) to only allow for SQL Server deployment? Basically I'm looking to eliminate this screen, or disable the file system deployment option.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do so ? It's a predefined wizard and as far as i know you cannot control options in wizard .

Comment: What version of SSIS? I did some investigation on this deployment tool and I found it totally inflexible. You can write your own automated deployment solution if you wish, using object models, command line tools etc. To me this deployment tool is pretty useless as it breaks two important change control rules: 1. It requires manual intervention, 2. It actually alters the deployables source code.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to build a small app which is based on the SSIS API and implement only the SQL Server deployment type. For un example, you can check this http://www.selectsifiso.net/?p=510